# How to get numbers from a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm using Oracle,

In a column I'm getting data like:

```
my_name 1234

my_name1 1234

my name (1234)

my name : 1234
```

These are name and ID(numeric)
name can contain numbers as well, but ID is always a number of 4-6 digits

I'm interested in the ID only.
I have decent understanding of regex in JS and Perl but I've no idea of it in Oracle SQL

I tried this : `regexp_replace('my_name - 7203', '[^[:digit:]]')`
which works fine but fails in cases when name contains numbers..

Comment: Is the name always followed by a space?

Comment: No. It can be my_name1:1234.

Comment: But there will always be a separator before the id that isn't a number (space, comma, parenteshis,etc.)?

Comment: @GrSrv: what about [`THIS`](http://regex101.com/r/bA4pA8) using this pattern `.*?([[:digit:]]+)\)?$` and replacing with `\1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
select regexp_replace('my_4name - 7203', '.*?([[:digit:]]+)[)]?$','\1')  from dual;
```

May this will help you.

Comment: It wont work for the case when the ID is on parenthesis.

Comment: Also it may be helpful to add a comment on your answer that if the OP has any thing enclosing the number it should be putted on your RE like : [1234] or {1234}

Comment: No need here for an opening parethesis in `[()]?` !!

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a pretty solution, it it should work as you want. Also I break it down on subqueries to be more understandeable.

The final replace would be:

```
substr( trim(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')), 
    regexp_instr( trim(
                        regexp_replace(name, 
                                       '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')), '[^[:digit:]]')+1, 
           length(trim(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')))) as ID
```

Check it here:

```
select substr( trim(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')), 
               regexp_instr(trim(
                regexp_replace( name, 
                    '[^[:digit:]]', 
        ' ')), '[^[:digit:]]')+1, 
               length(trim(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')))) as ID 
          from ( select 'my_name 1234' name from dual union all
                 select 'my_name1 1234' name from dual union all
                 select 'my name (1234)' name from dual union all
                 select 'my_name1:1234' name from dual union all
                 select 'my name : 1234' name from dual)
```

This is the version to be understanded:

```
select substr( justNumbers, 
               regexp_instr(justNumbers, '[^[:digit:]]')+1, 
               length(justNumbers)) as ID 
  from (select trim(regexp_replace(name, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')) as justNumbers
          from ( select 'my_name 1234' name from dual union all
                 select 'my_name1 1234' name from dual union all
                 select 'my name (1234)' name from dual union all
                 select 'my_name1:1234' name from dual union all
                 select 'my name : 1234' name from dual)
               )
```

The idea is to left just numbers then get it from the next character +1 that isn't a number (`regexp_instr(justNumbers, '[^[:digit:]]')+1`).

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression :  `[ \W ]+ ( \d\d\d\d [\d]? [\d]? )`  seems to work.

The pattern here is based on the data that the ID will be 4-6 digits long - `\d\d\d\d [\d]? [\d]?`

...in case the ID to be accepted gets longer than six digits, you could replace `[\d]?[\d]?` with  `[\d]*` . Also, the **assumption** is that the ID will be prefixed with a non-alphabetic character

**Example:**  `:` ,  `space` ,  `(`  etc...

`\W`  would take care of differentiating between any number of digits after "name" and the "ID".

**Test Run:**

```
input-  my name123456789:12345 
output-  12345
```